# SQL Index on Django Generic Relation

Tags: django, django-models, indexing, django-postgresql

Is it possible/sensible to create an SQL index on a GenericForeignKey in a Django model?

I want to perform a lookup on a large number of (~1 million) objects in my postgreSQL database. My lookup is based on a GenericForeignkey on the relevant model, which is actually stored as two fields: object_id (the pk of the object that is being linked to) and content_type (a FK to the Django ContentType model representing the type of object being linked to).

In SQL terms this is essentially:

```
WHERE ("my_model"."content_type_id" = x AND "my_model"."object_id" = y)
```

`object_id` is a non-unique field - since the generic FK can link to multiple models, its possible that objects of different types will have the same `pk`.

I am wondering whether I can speed up my query times by creating a non-unique index on `my_model.object_id`. My knowledge of indexing is limited, so I may not have understood their use correctly, but I know that Django automatically creates indexes on normal ForeignKey relations so I assume there is an associated speedup.

Has anyone had any experience creating indexes for GenericForeignKeys? Did you find a resulting performance increase? Any help or insight is much appreciated.

Comment: You could check the part of index in [the slide](http://www.slideshare.net/OReillyOSCON/unbreaking-your-django-application). Remember that you could create indexes in transaction and profile their performances easily.

Comment: although I can't answer your question directly, you can do some benchmarks youreslf, check out what indexes are already on your table,  explain the current query,( you can get this by printing QuerySet.query) Make the changes to the data schema (add indexes) and Explain the query again

Comment: Note also that an index doesn't have to be on just one column; if you have a 2-part key like this, you probably want an index across both columns. Note that the order can make a difference (indexing `(content_type_id, object_id)` is not quite the same as indexing `(object_id, content_type_id)`)